# platformRequest for call not working in j2me

Tags: java-me, call, lwuit, midp

I am building an application of telephone directory. I am using lwuit for ui building, so my application is running at MIDP2.1 and CDLC1.1. The application is targeted for nokia s40 devices.

When I am calling the `platformRequest` method from my form class with a constant number like this piece of code below, where `StartApp` is my main MIDlet.

```
     try 
        { 
    if (StartApp.getInstance().platformRequest("tel:01239201300") == true)
          {
            StartApp.getInstance().notifyDestroyed();
          }
       }
     catch(Exception ex)
     {
        System.out.println(ex);
     }
```

The application runs correctly and a call request is generated, but if I try to do this work like this piece of code below

```
   try{   
     String number = "tel:" + lblTelNumber.getText();
        System.out.println(number);
        if (StartApp.getInstance().platformRequest(number) == true)
        {
            StartApp.getInstance().notifyDestroyed();
        }
     }
   catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
```

This results in the following exception.

```
ordinary platformRequest: tel:01239201300 
URL is : tel:01239201300 
javax.microedition.io.ConnectionNotFoundException: Invalid Phone Number
at javax.microedition.midlet.MIDlet.platformRequest(+76)
at package1.InformationForm.Call(+48)
```

I don't know what is the problem here?

Comment: there is a chance to have invisible trailing spaces in your second code snippet. To find out whether it's so, modify your debugging message to something like `System.out.println("[" + number + "]")`, re-run your test and re-check the output

Comment: It seems like there is a new line character at the end of number, the number appears in comment as,[tel:01239201300
     ] 
(The second bracket is appearing in next line in comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a chance to have invisible symbols (eg trailing spaces) in your second code snippet.

To find out whether it's so, modify your debugging message to something like `System.out.println("[" + number + "]")`, re-run your test and re-check the output.

#### update

> It seems like there is a new line character at the end of number, the number appears in comment as, `[tel:01239201300 ]` (The second bracket is appearing in next line in comment).

Well that alone seem to be pretty sufficient to get `Invalid Phone Number`.

API documentation for [MIDlet.platformRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/midlet/MIDlet.html#platformRequest(java.lang.String)) refers to [RFC2806,](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2806.txt) for phone number URLs, which appears to pretty strictly specify what is allowed and what is not in section *2.2 "tel" URL scheme*.